# Base de Datos - Representacion de relaciones entre clases

Tags: base-de-datos

Buen dia!
Tengo dos clases, una llamada City

```
public class City {
private string name;
private int population;
private Country country;
}
```

y otra llamada Country

```
public class  Country {
 private string name;
 private List<City> cities;
}
```

No me queda muy en claro como representar esa relacion de las clases en el DER.
Hice una tabla llamada City que tiene como campos: 
Id , Name, Population, IdCountry.
y una llamada Country que tiene:
Id, Name.

Me parece como que Country me queda muy 'vacio', pero tambien pienso que con el id del country como FK de la tabla City, se pueden levantar todas las Ciudades que pertenezcan a ese pais y armar la lista!

La pregunta es si estoy en lo correcto o no se representan asi las relaciones.
Gracias!

Comment: La pregunta es sobre base de datos o sobre el uso de algún ORM como Hibernate? Ese código es Java, verdad?

Comment: Sobre base de datos en general. Sì, el codigo es Java pero en realidad mi pregunta es general, sea cual sea el lenguaje que utilice, como representar una relacion como la que describì en una base de datos. Gracias!!

Comment: Lo que se suele hacer es un modelo relacional en el cual: por `City` puedes saber el `Country` (casi como lo tienes ahora). Sería un modelo simplificado, pues si necesitaras por ejemplo la provincia, la región, etc... en cada unidad menor tendrías un id que identifique su pertenencia. Algo más o menos así: `Pais<-Region<-Provincia<-Ciudad<-Municipio<-Barrio`. Lo que no me queda claro es que tengas un lista de ciudades en `Country`. ¿Siempre que crees un objeto de ese tipo vas a necesitar una lista de sus ciudades?

Comment: Siguiendo lo dicho en el anterior comentario: `Pais<-Region<-Provincia<-Ciudad<-Municipio<-Barrio...` En **`barrio`** tendrías `id_municipio`; en **`municipio`** tendrías `id_ciudad`,  en **`ciudad`** tendrías `id_provincia`, en **`provincia`** tendrías `id_region` y en **`region`** tendrías `id_pais`. De ese modo, aunque estés en un barrio, podrás saber a qué país, región, provincia, ciudad y municipio pertenece, por las llaves foráneas que has ido poniendo de forma escalonada.

Comment: Lo que hiciste esta bien. Y si, queda vacio porque no tenes mas datos de paises.